# Why does my Rails method require a reload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This method below is giving me fits. My goal is that the method will always delete any order_notes where the title is equal to 'Fall Protection Warning'. Then, if `ismf_without_fall_protection?` is true, it will add in a new note.

But if the method doesn't have the line with the reload in it, it doesn't work right when `ismf_without_fall_protection?` is true; if I try to use the `collector.order_notes` collection elsewhere, it shows two order_notes instead of the one that I expected.

```
def reconcile_fall_protection
    collector.order_notes.where(title: 'Fall Protection Warning').destroy_all

    return unless ismf_without_fall_protection?

    collector.order_notes.reload #????

    collector.order_notes.create(title: 'Fall Protection Warning',
                                 description: 'No fall protection')

end
```

What gives? Is there a better way to do this that won't require the reload?

Comment: You need the reload because Ruby/Rails does not know if the `destroy_all` call has successfully destroyed every records of the scope. When you reload, you ask Rails to do a SQL query to get again the records of the scope. It is like a synchronisation between what is in the DB and what Rails has in its "cache"

Comment: @MrYoshiji - I understand what reload does, but is there a way to avoid it in this case?

Comment: I don't think so because Rails has no way to know what records were really destroyed unless using a SQL query to retrieve the remaining records. (it is perfectly fine to call `reload` on relations in Rails, there are situations like this one when it is needed to sync what Rails has "in mind" and what there is actually in the DB)

Answer (score 0):

The only real alternative to `reload` would be to call `reset`. This clears out the cached copy of the association.

The benefit to doing this over calling `reload` is that this defers the query that loads the association until it is actually needed (which may well be never) rather than always incurring it.

You could manually mutate the association target (`collector.order_notes.target`) removing the rows that have been deleting but this is probably error prone / fragile.